# Start Firefox update (nightly) without actually starting firefox

Tags: firefox, command-line-arguments, software-update

I'm running a nightly version of Firefox (aptly called "Nightly"), and there's a problem.
Given this is a nightly release, one of the recent updates, pretty much make Firefox unusable - it'll crash after around a minute of running and doing nothing.

Since this is around two or three days ago, at least one nightly release should've been pushed through now.

Is there a way, to engage the update process of Firefox, without actually starting Firefox? As in a command line option or something?

Comment: @screener The first answer of the question you linked to, actually provides pretty much a tip to what I was searching for: http://superuser.com/a/376564/46334 Thing is though, I'm thinking of adding my answer anyway, because I find it'll suit the question more directly. The other question asks about running a check, I asked more specifically about the update application.

Answer (score 3):

OK, I got it.

The easy way was to start Nightly in safe mode:

```
firefox --safe-mode
```

This started Nightly with almost every add-on, extension, etc. deactivated. I was able to then run the update normally from the "About" submenu.

But I decided to dig a little deeper.

It *is* possible to install updates directly from the command line. The Mozilla Wiki has an [article on that](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Software_Update%3aManually_Installing_a_MAR_file#Steps_for_Linux).

Important to note, is the file location of the `.mar` files. For nightly that is http://download.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/nightly/latest-trunk/ other versions, as well as `.mar` files for regular Firefox releases are also available in different directories on the same server.